# Search Box Webpart - Default to a custom search scope

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I've two search box webparts in a same page targeted to different audiences. I want to configure the search boxes to seach a specific search scopes which I've created.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom search control which redirects to the search page. I've passed all the necessary details such as keyword, scope etc in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the search box points to the page with the desired search results web part. That is a problem if you want both search boxes to point to the same page.  You might look at using web part connections and have 2 pairs of web parts - search box and results "A" and "B" where the "A" pair uses a connection to define the link.  Then the result part "A" would select the desired scope and/or audience and so forth.